# How to install melpa in emacs

Tags: software-installation, emacs

I need to install MELPA into my emacs 23.3 version. I have googled for the ways to install it but couldn't find/understand any of them.

Can anyone please help me with installing MELPA.   I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Question asked and answered on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991415/how-to-install-melpa-in-emacs